# Error in the console: "Failed to decode downloaded font"

Tags: fonts, console, gulp

When installing some fonts, the following error appears.

> Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/fonts/Manrope-ExtraBold.woff2
> OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: -2147370479
> I'm building the project on Gulp.

Only one font Lora does not give an error, although they are all set the same.
Previously, when building on Gulp, such errors did not occur.

Comment: @font-face{
  font-family: 'Manrope-ExtraBold';
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Manrope-ExtraBold'),
    url('../fonts/Manrope-ExtraBold.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/Manrope-ExtraBold.woff') format('woff');
  font-display: swap;
}